# PCA with components of the same size as the feature-vector

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection

I have implemented a model where I use PCA to reduce the dimensionality of my feature vectors. I would to look at how the model would perform if I skip the step of dimensionality reduction. As I have implemented quite some lines to normalize the vectors after PCA, it would be quite some work to "delete" PCA.

Now my Question is if I use as many components for PCA as the feautre-vector has dimensions, would the feature-vector after PCA still be the "same"? I know that the components of PCA would build a new coordinate system, but the vectors itself would still be of the same proportions right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a feature vector of size $p$ and use PCA selecting $p$ components, you will end up with a feature vector that has the same size as the original vector ($p$ variables), and that, globally, provide the same amount of information as the original vector. But individually, the variables would be different. From a start, your new $p$ variables after PCA would be uncorrelated with each other, while it is likely that your original variables have some sort of correlation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a little question regarding the new variables. If I look at my original feature vectors in the feature space and see that they are all within one cluster. Would the Vectors after PCA with the same dimension still be in a cluster?

Comment: I am not 100% sure of this, but my guess would be no, after PCA they may not be in one cluster because PCA works by projecting your observations into a new coordinate system and in this new coordinate system the observations may not be within just one cluster.